# How to iterate over subsets of a data frame and add column values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a file that is output from a program that has... idiosyncrasies.

```
image rightans trial response subject    condition accuracy  rt subtrial trainedOn
70_82.png   1   1070    Yes b232    Inconsistent    1   1530    70
9_100.png   0   1071    No  b232    Inconsistent    1   962 71
80_72.png   1   1072    Yes b232    Inconsistent    1   1138    72
14_75.png   0   1073    No  b232    Inconsistent    1   675 73
37_47.png   0   1074    No  b232    Inconsistent    1   1001    74
31_62.png   0   1075    No  b232    Inconsistent    1   672 75
62_1.png    1   1076    No  b232    Inconsistent    0   627 76
95_24.png   1   1077    Yes b232    Inconsistent    1   668 77
39_21.png   0   1078    No  b232    Inconsistent    1   801 78
24_54.png   0   1079    No  b232    Inconsistent    1   1033    79
82_44.png   1   1080    Yes b232    Inconsistent    1   1362    80
ShapeRadio-inconsistRadio
```

You'll notice that last line. That's a condition that doesn't vary within each `subject`.

How do I loop over the data frame in R and add that value to a "trained" column, but specific to each subject? There's another consistency that might be possible to exploit specifically: every 162 lines the `ShapeRadio-inconsistRadio` occurs. I'm hoping to advance my understanding of how to work with data frames with this question, and solve a problem all in one shot. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This was down voted without comment. How would I revise the question to better fit what's expected of one?

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, but I would encourage you to clarify exactly what you're looking for -- I can't tell by reading the question. What is the expected output for the file you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did. This worked perfectly, and cleaned the data to boot. I'm sure there's a more elegant, non-loop solution to this, but with very little R experience this is what I ended up with.

```
d <- read.csv('data.csv')

ids <- levels(d$subject)
ids <- ids[-1] # remove blank
trainedline = 161 # first line with trainedOn
# loop over logical filters for each id and change their trainedOn value
for (id in ids) {
    subjdata <- d[d$subject == id,] # logical index for subject
    trained <- as.character(d$image[trainedline]) # pull out the trained string
    d$trainedOn[which(d$subject == id)] <- trained # shove it in `trainedOn`
    trainedline = trainedline + 162 # increment the line number for the next subj
    next
}

# remove lines w/ NA
d.clean <- d[complete.cases(d),]

write.csv(d.clean, file = "clean_data.csv")
```